# Is there a way to create attribute from existing attributes in Microstrategy?

Tags: attributes, metrics, microstrategy

I am trying to extract the week number from a date using the Week function but it throws a syntax error that the existing Date is not an a metric. SO i duplicated the date attribute to a metric which basically makes it a derived metric. Now i am not able to use the Week function on this derived metric because apparently Week only supports a metric type as its argument. Need suggestions on this. Using this logic it seems it would be worthless to create new attributes using existing attributes because most functions support only metric as an argument

Answer (score 0):

You can do this out of the box if building the hierarchy as a derived object in Dossiers. Just Right-click the date object and select which elements of the time hierarchy you want created. They will be created on-the-fly as derived attributes.

If you want to implement as a true schema object attribute, you can use passthrough SQL in a new attribute to Achieve this. Depending on your database and SQL dialect, there will be variations, but the basic format is :

ApplySimple("DATEPART(week,#0)",YourDateAttribute)

The above code will be interpreted directly into the SQL and let the database calculate the week for this new attribute.